# Android NDK GLES v1.1

Tags: android-ndk

I got a game written in C/C++ using GLES v1.1 (yeah that was an iPhone game), as Im porting it to android I realize that I got some logs on the LogChat of Eclipse that tells me that the GL functionality (like glGet*) that I want to use is not implemented.

Digging on Google I found that you can cast a GL10 to GL11 context, however, since my API calls are all native, I cannot use that...

Is there a way to initialize a GL11 context in Java and then use the native GL11 API call?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running on the emulator, be aware that currently (SDK Tools Rev9, ndk-r5b) the emulator (no matter the platform version) only implements the GLES 1.0 interfaces.  It won't matter that your context is for GL11.  You'll need to test on hardware to successfully call the unimplemented API entry points.